# AngularJS- change ng-model's value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngulatJs(1.4). My Angular script creates two buttons(plus&minus)
so that users can increase/decrease product's quantity. It works fine. However, when I click update, it loads the page again and reset quantity to 1(`$scope.quantity=1;`). However, I want to assign the value of `<%=product['qty'].to_i%>"` to  `ng-model="quantity"`. Is it possible ?

```
var myapp = angular.module("mymodule", []);
myapp.controller('additctl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.quantity = 1;
    $scope.addval = function (val) {
        console.log(val);
        $scope.quantity = val + 1;
    }

    $scope.subval = function (val) {
        if (val > 0) {
            $scope.quantity = val - 1;
        }
    }
});
```

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="change_quantity" method="post">
    <div ng-controller="additctl">
        <button type="button" ng-click=subval(quantity)>-</button>
        <input type="number" ng-model="quantity" value="<%=product['qty'].to_i%>" min="1" max="99" required>
        <button type="button" ng-click=addval(quantity)>+</button>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="button" value="update">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: onload it will set $scope value to 1 as you have assigned 1 to   $scope.quantity=1;

Comment: you need to store them in cookies or some type of permanent storage

Comment: The current value(fetch from database) is in <%=product['qty'].to_i%>, I want to assign it to ng-model="quantity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that's possible. Just set it in the controller:

```
myapp.controller('additctl',function($scope){
    $scope.quantity = <%=product['qty'].to_i%>;
```

Make sure you remove the `value` attribute from the `<input>`.

If your JS is in a separate file, you can also do this:

1. Remove `$scope.quantity =` from your controller.
2. Set the value like this:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="quantity"
    ng-init="quantity = <%=product['qty'].to_i%>"
    min="1" max="99" required>
```

[`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) will run once, when the element is created.

Comment: I am using Rails4. I cannot use <%%> inside js file. It gives error.

Comment: So, the JS is in a separate file?

Comment: Yes, it is in separate file.